# Laravel Flash Message with Redirect Not Working

Tags: laravel-4

In a Laravel 4 project I am trying to set a flash message after the user's record is saved.

In my controller, I have:

```
return Redirect::to("/manage/users/$id")->with('success', 'Updated!');
```

Upon the redirect, if I dump `Session::all()` I get:

```
array(1) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "zXuGrG6OhA3bbPy5gzfYPzTm7LOFqX8vB1qxf9Sq" }
```

If I dump $_SESSION directly, I get:

```
array(3) [
    '_sf2_attributes' => array(1) [
        '_token' => string (40) "rQPKVHizgvCJLUxMS3JPvbpI2A1ZZUpV1mNFHX5O"
    ]
    '_sf2_flashes' => array()
    '_sf2_meta' => array(3) [
        'u' => integer 1404929806
        'c' => integer 1404929806
        'l' => string (4) "7200"
    ]
]
```

Does anyone know what may cause this or what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your sessions are actually working? Which session type are you using? Can you login ok?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you try Session::put('success', 'Updated'); instead of ->with('success', 'Updated') ?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange, I'm using the "native" driver. Session files are being created in app/storage/sessions but they are empty. I am able to login okay.

Comment: @faust Session::put() creates the same result.